# Git rebase using one combined diff, not one diff for each commit (without squashing commit history)

Tags: git, patch, rebase

I have a topic branch that I haven't worked on in a while, so the master branch has zoomed way passed it, meaning any merge/rebase is mostly going to be me resolving a billion conflicts.

So, still being a novice about git, I [read the manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) and rebasing is exactly what I want to do, however rather than solving the conflicts for each commit individually, I would rather just work with one large diff from topic-n back to where the fork occurred. (Lets just say that in the course of coding, the design changed a couple of times, and solving conflicts on a per-commit basis would require me to remember how it used to be two design iterations ago, produce that design again, only for the next few commits to modify it back to how I remember it to be. A side effect is that doing it commit by commit would also be a lot more work.)

I've done some mostly-futile googling (partially because I don't know how to describe this situation briefly), but I did for example find [this](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/combining-multiple-commits-into-one/), which would almost be what I want (after squashing the topic branch I would have only the one diff), but I would prefer to keep the commit history intact, which is the opposite of the goal of those instructions.

Frankly, even some tips on how to Google this further would be of use.

Comment: It seems to me you most likely want to merge the master branch into your topic branch.  That needs one single large resolution, and works with one single pair of diffs (from merge-base to tip of topic, vs merge-base to tip of `master`).

Comment: +1 for the merge. Rebase is really only meaningful if you want to go through every single commit and resolve the conflict one at a time. Or squash them all and apply the delta in one commit, losing history. Not losing history, but still only dealing with one big chunk of conflicts in one go: Merge!

Comment: @torek, really? I assumed it would work the same way, commit by commit... dang. I'll give it a shot, thanks